# How to Import SVG to Unity and still keeps the Group(Layer)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg, vector-graphics

I just import a SVG file into Unity2018.4.6f1 by `Vector Graphics` package, but it can not keeps the `groups(layer)` in the SVG file. The package just make it become a sprite.
Is there any way to `keep its group(layer)`?

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't natively support SVG files, so it will turn into a sprite and you can't use groups. Everything the Vector Graphics package can do is [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html) if you want to read more.

The third party assets as well (the ones I've checked) do not support this.